# Redirect response location

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, redirect, loopback

I want to redirect response to CURL link, but I receive error message

> "Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client"

I using loopback response

```
import { Response as loopResponse } from '@loopback/rest';
```

this is my code

```
 @inject(RestBindings.Http.RESPONSE) private loopResponse: loopResponse,
async dashboardGenerate(
    @param.query.string('workgroupId') workgroupId: string,
    @param.query.string('period') period: string,
    @param.query.string('historyDepth') historyDepth: number,
    @param.query.string('reportDate') reportDate: string,
  )  {
    const resp = await report.dashboardExport(
            reportDate,
          );
          const respBody = resp.body;
          this.logger.info('response: ', respBody);
          const params = {
            Bucket: fileBucket,
            Key: respBody.data.path.slice(1, -1),
            Expires: 400,
          };
          const curl = s3.getSignedUrl(Constants.SIGNED_URL_OPERATIONS.get, params);
          this.logger.info('curl: ', curl);
          return this.loopResponse.redirect(curl);
}
```